# How to test *ngFor in Angular 2?

Tags: unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

I am new to Angular and created To-Do Application. I tried to find the solution at many places even the [Testing documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html) 
 
I am testing a component. That bring data from mongodb, I have mocked that data though.

The following is the HTML of template (using bootstrap):

```
<li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let task of tasks">
    <div class=" task-date">{{task.date}}</div>
</li>
```

The below is the component code (I'm adding only sub-part):

```
export class ShowTaskComponent extends OnInit{

tasks:Task[];

ngOnInit() {
  setInterval(() => {this.refreshTasks()}, 3000);
}

constructor(private appService: AppService, private _router:Router){
  super();
  this.refreshTasks();
}

refreshTasks = function() {

  this.appService.retrieveDataFromServer().subscribe((data: any) => {

    //this.appService.taskArray = data;

    this.tasks = data;

  });

};
}
```

Now I'm adding the test code (.spec.ts file's sub part) ... To explain well, all of the code (excluding imports):

```
  let comp: ShowTaskComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ShowTaskComponent>;
  let service: AppService;
  let router: Router;

  let debugTaskTitle: DebugElement[];
  let taskTitles: any[];

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ShowTaskComponent],
      providers: [AppService],
      imports: [....]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach( () => {

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShowTaskComponent);
    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AppService);
    router = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Router);

    let dummyTasks: any[] = [
      {
        "date": "12 October 2017",
        "title": "Demo task 1",
        "description": "Demo task 1 desc",
        "priority" : "High",
        "_id" : "1"
      },
      {
        "date": "1 January 2018",
        "title": "Demo task 2",
        "description": "Demo task 2 desc",
        "priority" : "Low",
        "_id" : "2"
      }
    ];

    spyOn(service, 'retrieveDataFromServer').and.returnValue(Observable.of<any[]>(dummyTasks));


    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShowTaskComponent);
    comp = fixture.componentInstance;
    console.log("----------------------------> comp ", comp);

    debugTaskTitle = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('div.task-title'));
    console.log("----------------------------> debugTaskTitle ", debugTaskTitle);

    let counter: number = 0;

    for(let title of debugTaskTitle) {
      taskTitles.push(title.nativeElement);
      taskTitles[counter].innerText = dummyTasks[counter].title;
      counter ++;
    }
  });

  //This test fails because taskTitles is undefined!
  it('test whether a correct test has loaded', () =>{

    expect(taskTitles).toBe(["Demo task 1", "Demo task 2"]);
  });
```

The problem comes with **debugTaskTitle**. This is empty array, when I try to initialise it with `fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css())`.

I tried to print it on console (look at long --------> arrows) and it is empty array.

The object of the component **comp** is created and is doing great.

Can anybody suggest me where I'm wrong? I'm late in submitting this assignment by three days. Any help will be great.

Whole code is at [github repo](https://github.com/ashishknoldus/angular-assignment-with-tests/)

Also, I don't see anything on browser when I run only first test. It should show tasks on browser!

So does that mean *ngFor doesn't populate the content on page once `.compileComponents();` has been called to generate CSS and HTML within first `beforeEach()`?

Comment: import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since `retrieveDataFromServer` returns an Observable, you need to wait for the async task to resolve. For that you can wrap the beforeEach in `async`, just like the one above it. Then you need to wait for it to stabilize

```
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShowTaskComponent);
comp = fixture.componentInstance;

fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    // after something in the component changes, you should detect changes
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // everything else in the beforeEach needs to be done here.
    debugTaskTitle = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('div.task-title'));
    ...
})
```

#### UPDATE

Note that it is now recommended to use `fakeAsync` over `async` now. Unless the test makes an XHR request, which `fakeAsync` cannot handle, `fakeAsync` is the preferred method to use when testing asynchronous code. What `fakeAsync` does is allow you to write code as if it was synchronous and let you control when to complete the async test. Some test code might look something like

```
import { fakeAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';

it('should...', fakeAsync(() => {
  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ShowTaskComponent);
  comp = fixture.componentInstance;

  comp.callSomeAsyncMethod();
  tick();

  fixture.detectChanges();
  // assertions
}));
```

Comment: every single time i forget the "whenStable" :)

Comment: none of the way is working, getting empty array